# sorting multiple column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this :

```
key   value   rating

1      1       1

0      0       3

0      1       2
```

First i want to order the table by rating column in descending order and for those rows where value column is 1 , it should be ordered by key in descending order. So the resulting table has to be like this:

```
key   value   rating

0      0       3

1      1       1

0      1       2
```

i have tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY CASE `value` WHEN 1 THEN `key` 
        END 
 `table`.`pair` desc
```

Comment: What should happen if there's another record  with `value=0` and `rating=2`?

Comment: @default locale : actually the third column is a date time field in my real table. so the values in the third column will be unique. i have changed the column names for this question

Comment: well, you can substitute numbers back to corresponding dates :) My question is: if you have *non-special* value with rating equal to *special* value which record should go first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify how records with `value=1` and `value<>1` should be ordered in respect to each other. So, I'll guess that `value=1` records will come last:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY
    (
    CASE
        WHEN value=1 THEN -1
        ELSE rating
    END
    ) desc,
    key desc
```

If you have negative ratings you can replace `-1` with your negative limit. The goal is to sort `value=1` records separately.

Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65ae28/2). I added some records to illustrate issues in the problem statement.

Currently it's unclear from your question how records like `(0,1,4)`, `(1,1,2)` and `(0,0,3)` should be ordered.

Comment: when i run this query,  i am getting {0,0,3}, {0,1,2}, {1,1,1}. So its ordered by rating . but its not ordered by key in descending order

Comment: Please check out the updated question. First time, I forgot `key desc`, but now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `order by`. Use `case` statement to custom the sort order

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN value = 0 THEN rating
            ELSE key
          END DESC
```